# Extract specific columns from list

Tags: python

I have a list that contain the column indexes as follows:

```
list1 = [0 ,2]
```

Another list of list would contain the file contents of a csv file as follows:

```
list2=[["abc", 1, "def"], ["ghi", 2, "wxy"]]
```

What can be the best way to create a new list that would only contain the values from `list2` with the column numbers that are contained in `list1` i.e.

```
newList = [["abc", "def"], ["ghi", "wxy"]]
```

I am having a hard time creating the sublists

Comment: You could have told us what you tried, at least in pseudocode (hence the -1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `List Comprehension` : -

```
newList = [[each_list[i] for i in list1] for each_list in list2]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the OP wants.  Given columns [0, 2] in `list1`, newList should contain those columns for each row in `list2`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are happy with a list of tuples, you can use `operator.itemgetter`

```
import operator
list1 = [0,2]
my_items = operator.itemgetter(*list1)
new_list = [ my_items(x) for x in list2 ]
```

(or you could use `map` here):

```
new_list = map(my_items, list2)
```

and as a 1 liner:

```
new_list = map(operator.itemgetter(*list1), list2)
```

`operator.itemgetter` probably has a slight performance advantage over nested list-comprehensions, but it's likely to be small enough that it's not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> list1 = [0 ,2]
>>> list2=[["abc", 1, "def"], ["ghi", 2, "wxy"]]
>>> newList = [[l[i] for i in list1] for l in list2]
>>> print newList
[['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'wxy']]
```

Answer (score 5):

Extracting directly some columns from a python list of lists is not possible because exactly python does not perceive this list as an array (which has by definition rows and columns) but as a list of lists.

However, you can do something like this very easily without using any list comprehension by using `Numpy`. Specifically, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [0 , 2]
list2=[["abc", 1, "def"], ["ghi", 2, "wxy"]]

# Covert list2 to numpy array
array2 = np.array(list2)

# Extract the specific columns from array2 according to list1
newArray = array2[:, list1]

#  Convert the new numpy array to list of lists
newList = newArray.tolist()

# newList is the following list: [['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'wxy']]
```

I hope that this helps too!

Comment: loved the explanatory introduction to your answer, well done! +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with csv files, you don't need to reinvent the wheel. 
Take a look at the excellent `csv` module.

Answer (score 1):

You could put [Poete Maudit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125711/10101556) into one line like so:

```
column = np.array(list_name)[:,column_number].tolist()
```

You could also keep it as a numpy array by removing `.tolist()`